# Can I discard the complex portion of results generated with scipy.linalg.logm?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

I have a matrix that look like the one below. It is always a square matrix (up to 1000 x 1000) with the values are between 0 and 1:

```
data = np.array([[0.0308, 0.07919, 0.05694, 0.00662, 0.00927],
                 [0.07919, 0.00757, 0.00720, 0.00526, 0.00709],
                 [0.05694, 0.00720, 0.00518, 0.00707, 0.00413],
                 [0.00662, 0.00526, 0.00707, 0.01612, 0.00359],
                 [0.00927, 0.00709, 0.00413, 0.00359, 0.00870]])
```

When I try to take the natural log of this matrix, using `scipy.linalg.logm`, it gives me the following result.

```
print(logm(data))

>> [[-2.3492917 +1.42962407j  0.15360003-1.26717846j  0.15382223-0.91631624j  0.15673496+0.0443927j   0.20636448-0.01113953j]
    [ 0.15360003-1.26717846j -3.75764578+2.16378501j  1.92614937-0.60836013j -0.13584605+0.27652444j  0.27819383-0.25190565j]  
    [ 0.15382223-0.91631624j  1.92614937-0.60836013j -5.08018989+2.52657239j  0.37036433-0.45966441j -0.03892575+0.36450564j]
    [ 0.15673496+0.0443927j  -0.13584605+0.27652444j  0.37036433-0.45966441j -4.22733838+0.09726189j  0.26291385-0.07980921j]
    [ 0.20636448-0.01113953j  0.27819383-0.25190565j -0.03892575+0.36450564j  0.26291385-0.07980921j -4.91972246+0.06594195j]]
```

First of all, why is this happening? Based on another post I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765310/scipy-linalg-eig-return-complex-eigenvalues-for-covariance-matrix), pertaining to a different scipy.linalg method, this is due to truncation and rounding issues caused by floating point errors.

**If that is correct, then how am I able to fix it?** The second answer on that same linked post suggested this:

> (2) All imaginary parts returned by numpy's linalg.eig are close to the machine precision. Thus you should consider them zero.

Is this correct? I can use `numpy.real(data)` to simply discard the complex portion of the values, but I don't know if that is a mathematically (or scientifically) robust thing to do.

Additionally I attempted to use tensorflow's linalg.logm method, but got the exact same complex results meaning this isn't unexpected behavior?

Comment: If you discard the imaginary parts, the result is no longer a correct matrix logarithm of the input array.  Why are you computing a matrix logarithm?  What are you going to do with it?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yeah, that's why I was skeptical of the linked comment's suggestion to do so.

For the matrix, I am taking the log and then subsequently calculating Pearson correlations for each pair of columns (e.g. 1 & 2, 1 & 3, etc.).

Comment: I should clarify my comment: in the general case, it would be incorrect to discard the imaginary part.  But if you know *a priori* that your matrix should have a real matrix logarithm, and you check that any imaginary parts in the result are "small", then you can probably safely discard the imaginary part.  This is not the case for your array `data`.

Comment: *"I am taking the log and then subsequently calculating Pearson correlations for each pair of columns..."*  Interesting--why are you doing that?  Are you sure you want the [matrix logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix) and not just the elementwise scalar logarithm?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser That is... and incredibly good point. I've been following the methods section from a publication and just blindly assumed I should be getting the logarithm of the matrix. This had me take a second look and the language does make it sound likely that I should be looking at this element wise.
*The matrix values were transformed by the natural logarithm and for each pair of columns the Pearson correlation coefficient was calculated to arrive at the correlation matrix*