# Solving a large (150 variable) system of linear, ordinary differential equations; running into floating point rounding and/or stiffness problems

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, numerical-methods, differential-equations

**EDIT**: Original post too vague. I am looking for an algorithm to solve a large-system, solvable, linear IVP that can handle very small floating point values. Solving for the eigenvectors and eigenvalues is impossible with `numpy.linalg.eig()` as the returned values are complex and should not be, it does not support `numpy.float128` either, and the matrix is not symmetric so `numpy.linalg.eigh()` won't work. Sympy could do it given an infinite amount of time, but after running it for 5 hours I gave up. `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp()` works with implicit methods (have tried Radau and BDF), but the output is wildly wrong. Are there any libraries, methods, algorithms, or solutions for working with this many, very small numbers?

Feel free to ignore the rest of this.

I have a 150x150 sparse (~500 nonzero entries of 22500) matrix representing a system of first order, linear differential equations. I'm attempting to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix to construct a function that serves as the analytical solution to the system so that I can just give it a time and it will give me values for each variable. I've used this method in the past for similar 40x40 matrices, and it's **much** (tens, in some cases hundreds of times) faster than `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp()` and also makes post model analysis much easier as I can find maximum values and maximum rates of change using `scipy.optimize.fmin()` or evaluate my function at `inf` to see where things settle if left long enough.

This time around, however, `numpy.linalg.eig()` doesn't seem to like my matrix and is giving me complex values, which I know are wrong because I'm modeling a physical system that can't have complex rates of growth or decay (or sinusoidal solutions), much less complex values for its variables. I believe this to be a stiffness or floating point rounding problem where the underlying LAPACK algorithm is unable to handle either the very small values (smallest is ~3e-14, and most nonzero values are of similar scale) or disparity between some values (largest is ~4000, but values greater than 1 only show up a handful of times).

I have seen suggestions for similar users' problems to use sympy to solve for the eigenvalues, but when it hadn't solved my matrix after 5 hours I figured it wasn't a viable solution for my large system. I've also seen suggestions to use `numpy.real_if_close()` to remove the imaginary portions of the complex values, but I'm not sure this is a good solution either; several eigenvalues from `numpy.linalg.eig()` are 0, which is a sign of error to me, but additionally almost all the real portions are of the same scale as the imaginary portions (exceedingly small), which makes me question their validity as well. My matrix is real, but unfortunately not symmetric, so `numpy.linalg.eigh()` is not viable either.

I'm at a point where I may just run `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp()` for an arbitrarily long time (a few thousand hours) which will probably take a long time to compute, and then use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()` to approximate the analytical solutions I want, since I have a good idea of their forms. This isn't ideal as it makes my program much slower, and I'm also not even sure it will work with the stiffness and rounding problems I've encountered with `numpy.linalg.eig()`; I suspect Radau or BDF would be able to navigate the stiffness, but not the rounding.

Anybody have any ideas? Any other algorithms for finding eigenvalues that could handle this? Can `numpy.linalg.eig()` work with `numpy.float128` instead of `numpy.float64` or would even that extra precision not help?

I'm happy to provide additional details upon request. I'm open to changing languages if needed.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically are not a good fit for this site.  Split your task into smaller ones and start working on them. And ask particular questions related to particular issues you encounter. Here's how: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @itprorh66 is my edit any better? I'm not sure there's a way to be more specific with this ask, honestly.

Comment: Given the nature of floating point numbers, I don't believe it would be a problem to solve a matrix for eigenvalues with very small values. It could potentially be a problem if you had very large and very small values together, though. How sure are you that complex solutions are inappropriate? Lots of physical systems exhibit sinusoidal behavior under some conditions, even though under normal conditions those sinusoidal behaviors are drowned out by other terms.

Comment: [Here’s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765310/scipy-linalg-eig-return-complex-eigenvalues-for-covariance-matrix) a less extreme example where `numpy.linalg.eig()` produced complex numbers for another user, and the culprit seems to be rounding of small numbers. My largest and smallest numbers are mentioned in the original post. I am certain these functions are not periodic; they model radioactive mass transport, and the decays and movements are exponential with real exponents.

Comment: Did you try using the sparse methods from scipy.sparse.linalg? In the cited example, already in the construction of the covariance matrix rounding errors get introduced that make the matrix non-symmetric and with higher or full rank. Here with the generic algorithm the initial transformation to Hessenberg form will destroy the sparse structure and introduce random floating-point errors. // Also, why not use the built-in `expm` functions?

Comment: Thank you, @LutzLehmann! These are the exact kind of answers I'm looking for. I was unfamiliar with the matrix exponential as a solution for systems of linear ODEs, but even just glancing at wikipedia tells me it's worth using here. I was also unfamiliar with `scipy.sparse.linalg()` and was really hoping something like this existed, but my googling hadn't turned it up at all. I'll try both these out and come back with results. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome! ⚠️️ Software recommendation questions are **off-topic** here for the reasons explained in #3 of [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment chain above the best solution for this is to use a [Matrix Exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential), which is a lot simpler (and apparently less error prone) than diagonalizing your system with eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

For my case I used `scipy.sparse.linalg.expm()` since my system is sparse. It's fast, accurate, and simple. My only complaint is the loss of evaluation at infinity, but it's easy enough to work around.